# How can I add an object to <? extends Interface>?

Tags: java, object, generics

```
public interface A {
    int getA();
}

public class MyObj implements A {
    public int getA(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If have a Map : `Map<? extends A, String> aMap = new HashMap<>();`

How can I add an `MyObj` to this `aMap` ? Or how should be the class `MyObj` so that it can work in this map

Comment: You'll need to elaborate a bit more coherently for us to be able to help you

Comment: `java.util.Map` works on two objects. `key` and `value`. How do you want to use `MyObj` .... as key or value ?

Comment: "How can i add an MyObj to this aMap" You can't, unless your key is `null`.

Comment: "You can't, unless your key is null" he can, if he add his object as a key

Comment: @degr no, you really can't. Really really. Try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can i add an `MyObj` to this `aMap` ?

You can't, because of the upper bound on the key type.

The reason is that `? extends A` could be `MyOtherObj implements A`. In this case, it would be type-unsafe to be able to put a key of type `MyObj` into the map:

```
Map<MyOtherObj, String> anotherMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<? extends A, String> aMap = anotherMap;
aMap.put(new MyObj(), "");  // Can't do this; but if you could...

MyOtherObj obj = anotherMap.keySet().iterator().next();  // ClassCastException!
```

Remember the acronym PECS (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) for a lot more detail):

- Producer `extends`
- Consumer `super`

In other words, `Map<? extends A, String>` can only be used to *produce* instances of `A`, it can't consume/accept instances of `A`.

For example, you can iterate the keys ("producing" the keys):

```
for (A a : aMap.keySet()) { ... }
```

The map can only "consume" a literal `null`:

```
aMap.put(null, "");
```

because `null` can be cast to any type without exception. But there's not much use in a map which only has a single key - you may as well just store the value directly.

The only way to do this type-safely is to put the instance of `MyObj` into the map via a reference which you *know* accepts `MyObj` instances:

```
Map<MyObj, String> safeMap = new HashMap<>();
safeMap.put(new MyObj(), "");

Map<? extends A, String> aMap = safeMap;
```

or

```
Map<A, String> safeMap = new HashMap<>();
safeMap.put(new MyObj(), "");

Map<? extends A, String> aMap = safeMap;
```

But you should consider not having the wildcard-typed map at all; `Map<MyObj, String>` or `Map<A, String>` is easier.

Comment: I would add the simple advice to use a `Map<A,String>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Your compiler won't allow it.

You have to change your Map to:

```
Map<A, String> aMap = new HashMap<>();
```

After this you can use put to add an element to it:

```
aMap.put(new MyObj(), "myObject");
```